# Inserting JavaScript at runtime in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, runtime, appendchild

I'm using a script to load scripts from a library (a big file) it works like this:

1. Load a script via xmlhttprequest
2. Creates a new script tag element with the script inside (new text node, innerText or
   innerHTML)
3. Appends the new element in the head

Nothing very complicated. But IE8 just didn't do the job! It doesn't allow to insert the script in the script element tag by any method! So I try another approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function teste(){
    var elemScript = document.createElement('script');
    elemScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    elemScript.language = 'javascript';
    elemScript.src = 'http://somewhere/somecode.js';
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    headTag.appendChild(elemScript);
}
window.onload = teste;
</script>
```

IE8 just doesn't say anything. I don't know if it is loading, but I'm sure is not executing the code (an alert for testing).
I know that jQuery and other libraries do this and can make it work in all browsers (IE8+ will be fine to me). How they do this magic? Is there a simple way to solve this with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

The ajax doesn't fire the onload event:

```
window.onload = teste;
```

So, just change it to call the method:

```
teste();
```

Comment: It is firing, there is a confirmation inside teste() that I didn't include to simplify the code.

Comment: I don't know how it is firing the onload on ajax update, because the page has already been loaded. But have you tried calling `teste();`?

Comment: This script is in the head, it's loaded before the bottom of the page. If there is some DOM reference that wasn't load yet, it will not work, so I allways write like this - a good programming practice.